# Trying to create an Xcode Objective-C function that records a video capture of my UIView contents and saves to phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, screen-capture

I'm trying to create an Xcode Objective-C function that can be called from a button tap, that will record the contents of a UIView and its subviews (or a fixed section of the screen e.g. 320x320 in the center) and then allow the user to save the video to their iPhone camera roll. I also want to include the audio that is being played by the app at the time of the recording e.g background music and sound effects.

I'm having trouble finding any info on this as their seems to be a lot of people trying to record their running app for external purposes like the app store video preview. I need my video captured within the app, to be used as an app feature.

Does anyone know if this can be done or know a website or tutorial where I can learn what's needed? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is two years old, but for anybody who comes along who might need to record their iOS app's screens and save them to the phone's camera roll or even a specific URL, take a look at https://github.com/alskipp/ASScreenRecorder

I've tried it and it works!  The frames per second aren't 60 so I don't know how well it would work if you were trying to record an action game, but it's still pretty awesome.

Comment: not record for camera capture function how to record this one function objective c application any know guys please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with just one function, check that project:
https://github.com/coolstar/RecordMyScreen

Comment: Thanks but I looked at this but couldn't get it to work. I also paid for a script called ScreenCaptureView but this also doesn't seem to work with updated architecture.